# Set Variable value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have declared the variable for v_error but when inside my begin I do set a number value for the variable I get a error under the equals 'Syntax Error'

Code Below:

```
DECLARE 
    v_error varchar(1);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE :v_tab1';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
            set @v_error = 0;  — error here

            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table does not exist!');
        ELSE             
            RAISE;                  
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Exception Occurred on table drop' );
            v_error := '1';
        END IF;
END;
```

Comment: `@v_error` This is used in `SQL SEVER` for instance to assign values to variable. In Oracle you need to use operator `:=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping aside the usage of `:v_tab1`, which strongly depends on the client/tool you use to run this code, you need to edit your syntax  according to what you already do a few lines after:

```
DECLARE 
    v_error varchar(1);
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE :v_tab1';
EXCEPTION                
WHEN OTHERS THEN     
    IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN            
        v_error := '0'; /*    <------ like you do for v_error := '1'; */

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('This table does not exist!');
    ELSE             
        RAISE;                  
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Exception Occurred on table drop' );
        v_error := '1';                  
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I've added your changed and also added a DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line to print out the v_error variable and it doesn't print out the error code

Comment: Maybe you need `set serveroutput on` (SQL*Plus) or any other set up to enable the output, depending on your client/tool

Comment: Also maybe move the second `dbms_output` to before the `raise` (or better still, give the 942 exception its own handler and allow anything else to fail on its own, but that would require a bit of restructuring).